# HashMAp in android

Tags: android, hashtable

I am using spinner in my application,in that i am using a hashtable.In that if user selects an entry from Spinner array the corresponding key value of that entry should be passed to another screen.Please anybody help me.

My Code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    Spinner spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);        
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this,R.array.Source, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
            HashMap hm = new HashMap(); 
            hm.put("Chennai","123");
            menuItems.add(hm);         
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please make clear that you are using hashtable only as a datasource of the spinner, or a list of hashtable.

Comment: Hi  jeet &  yogesh kamaliya ,i have posted my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try by replacing this code

```
 HashMap hm = new HashMap(); 
            hm.put("Chennai","123");
```

with

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            hm.put("Chennai","123");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                int item = sp.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "You have selected the book: " + androidBooks[item], 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
            
        });
```

in toast you get selected item 
 pass this item to another screen.